# Bootstrap navbar button not clickable on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

'm not sure what I'm doing wrong… however here is my problem:

On this website: http://blog.cast.zhdk.ch/360/ I made with bootstrap, I created a menu where the «sandwich» menu button appears on all devices. I added some text to it.
It's not working on smartphone (tested on my iPhone 6, iOS 9.2); if I press the menu button just nothing happens. It works like a charm on my desktop iMac with the newest version Firefox. I couldn't find any HTML errors.

Here is my navbar source code for the wordpress theme (with a bootstrap navwalker):

```
      <!-- Static navbar -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'Primary Menu',
                    'theme_location'    => '360-menu',
                    'depth'             => 1,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

Comment: Well this is embarassing… I just deleted my browser cache on mobile and seems to be working on mobile, too. Maybe anyone wants to confirm that it works?

Comment: My experience with wordpress is it is heavily cached. Try adding some bogus parameters to the url, like `?a=1`. I've found that is a useful way to clear the cache.

Comment: @michael it seems working in iphone6 but only menu has come with disarranged in alignment.

Comment: @ Matt Creemens @PrajwalShrestha Thanks for checking. What do you mean with «disarranged in alignment».